# VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm getting the following error when using matplotlib.plot. Am i supposed to change the code provided by Matplotlib (ie. specify 'dype=object')? or is there another way to do it?

`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:263: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray c = np.array(c)`

Comment: Could you add the code and some test data that reproducrs this? And the full error trace? Are you using the latest matplotlib?